# Passing dataset or datatable between two pages u

Tags: javascript, datatable, popup, dataset, parent-child

I've a popup to enter the data and once the data is added, I need to show data in parent page Gridview. But that data don't need to be stored until I click the save button below the Gridview in the parent page. It will still be displayed and maintained on the screen - (like it has active/inactive button).

When I click the save below the gridview, it will be stored in the database all at once. I need to do this using javascript. How can I do that?

I'm working on asp.net web project.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your data temporarily using `localStorage` instead of your database for instance:

```
localStorage.setItem('myDataName', 'myDataValue') // Save data
```

And:

```
localStorage.getItem('myDataName') // Get data
```

This works for strings. If you want to save objects or arrays of objects, you must convert them to strings like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('myDataName', JSON.stringify(myObject)) // Save object
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but how do I get the localStorage to bind the datagrid. As I've to show the data added from popup in the gridview in parent page.

Comment: Are you using a custom grid for your project or just a library? If so let me know the name of the library you're using so I can further help you.

Comment: No, it is simple asp:Gridview, which I was binding using dataset and using DataBind method.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

> The localStorage property allows you to access a local Storage object.
>   localStorage is similar to sessionStorage. The only difference is
>   that, while data stored in localStorage has no expiration time, data
>   stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the browsing session
>   ends—that is, when the browser is closed.
>
> It should be noted that data stored in either localStorage or
>   sessionStorage is specific to the protocol of the page.

**Store Data**

```
localStorage.setItem('Key', 'YOUR_DATA');
```

**Read Data**

```
var YOUR_DATA = localStorage.getItem('Key');
```

> You can also store objects by stringifying it.

```
localStorage.setItem('Key', JSON.stringify(YOUR_DATA_OBJ));
```

> when reading parse to object

```
var YOUR_DATA_OBJ = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Key'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but how do I get the localStorage to bind the datagrid. As I've to show the data added from popup in the gridview in parent page.